# Inline Elements With Width

Tags: html, css, width, inline

This question seems to be asked freqeuently over the internet but I still can't find a solution.

I have this navigation bar (It switches between tabs using jQuery) which displays inline. I'm showing a background image on these and to make them more definitive I need to make them wider and higher.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="tabs-nav-cont">
    <li class="tabs-navs"><a href="#tabs-1">Nav 1</div></a></li>
    <li class="tabs-navs"><a href="#tabs-2">Nav 2</div></a></li>
    <li class="tabs-navs"><a href="#tabs-3">Nav 3</div></a></li>
    <li class="tabs-navs"><a href="#tabs-4">Nav 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The only way I can seem to do this is by reverting them back to block elements. Which is not what I want because they display vertically. So I tried putting divs in the anchors so I can size them up. However they seem to change them back to block elements too.

Im confused. Someone please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily you live in the year 2009, where inline-block is widely adopted through browsers: [Cross browser inline-block](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/).

If it's just for the height (and all the content of the `li`s fits each on one line), you'd like to go with `line-height: 123px`, which sets the height of an inline box to 123px (per line, that is).

Or, quite common, if the navigation is left-aligned, float them:

```
#nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Well thank god for 2009. I had no idea that inline-block existed. Thank you!

Comment: ;-) @Ben: You're welcome. @Stobor: I visited the link just last week again, so it was kind of reachable in my browser history.

Answer (score 1):

Because it was not 2009 when i first had to solve this :) i got the solution for firefox with following css class:

```
.ib { display: -moz-inline-block; display: inline-block;}
```

This is my generic inline-block class that i use where necessary...

Sinan.