# Setting the width of inline elements

Tags: html, css, xhtml

> You can set the width of inline elements like `<span>`, `<em>` and `<strong>`, but you won’t notice any effect until you position them.

a) I thought the width of inline an inline element can’t be set?

b) Assuming width can be set - we won’t notice any effects ( thus the width we specify ) until we position inline element. Position how/where?

c) Why is the width of inline elements apparent only when we “position” them?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085980/inline-elements-with-width?rq=1 (but this is the better question).

Comment: Related: [Inline HTML elements don't allow setting "width" - why is that?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/404472/inline-html-elements-dont-allow-setting-width-why-is-that)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As others have mentioned, setting the width (or some other position-related property) of an inline element will cause the browser to then display the element as a block element.

You can explicitly declare this sort of behavior through using the CSS `display` property. The most common settings are `display: inline` (default), `display: block`, and `display: none`. 
A full reference for the `display` property is available [here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

However, it should be noted that the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) discourages the use of "overriding the conventional interpretation of HTML elements":

> Style sheets provide the means to
>   specify the rendering of arbitrary
>   elements, including whether an element
>   is rendered as block or inline. In
>   some cases, such as an inline style
>   for list elements, this may be
>   appropriate, but generally speaking,
>   authors are discouraged from
>   overriding the conventional
>   interpretation of HTML elements in
>   this way.

Comment: "*setting the width [..] of an inline element will cause the browser to then display the element as a block*". Are you sure?

Comment: "setting the width … will cause the browser to then display the element as a block element" — That's nonsense. You can set the width, but it won't apply to the element.

Comment: @donut "setting the width (or some other position-related property) of an inline element will cause the browser to then display the element as a block element."
--
 Any authoritative documentation source on this?

Comment: "setting the width … will cause the browser to then display the element as a block element"  is FALSE. As @Stef said, "When you "position" an inline element by using position:absolute, you are making it a block element, whose width is interpreted by the browser." You cannot set a width for an inline element.

Comment: @Orial question is totally relevant: the behavior is browser dependent. For example, Opera (at least from version 89) will not change a default display (inline) to a block even if width is specified in the css. Instead, opera will ignore the width

Answer (score 69):

There's also the option of **display: inline-block**, which might give you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Very nice! Here's a nice [compatibility matrix](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html). Today, `display: inline-block` is almost safe to use

Comment: Though works, still some pretty janky/unexpected behavior when inserting elements into it dynamically. Not sure why.

Comment: Robert Nyman has a [nice blogpost on inline-block](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/).

Comment: *Sometimes* `inline-flex` can be better, in my case for MDI.

Answer (score 20):

a) The width of an inline element is ignored

b,c) When you "position" an inline element (I assume that means using *position:absolute*), you are actually making it a block element, whose width is interpreted by the browser

Comment: Great. It's very important to know this when we don't have control over the HTML as in Umbraco Contour generated forms. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 7):

That basically means that if you apply `position: absolute` to inline element, it will become block element and gain width.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's due to the fact that when you specify position attributes for an "inline" element, the element is no longer being displayed *inline* and instead is being treated as a block-level element.

Answer (score 0):

a. Width of inline elements are ignored.

b. Actually you can apply width to element if set `display: inline-block;` but to see results you also should apply `overflow: hidden;`.

To have all benefits of inline and block types you can use follow snippet:

`display: inline-block;
width: 50%; // or px, em, etc.
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;`

In this case you can manage width and have text ellipsis feature.

Answer (score 0):

Inline element cannot have width. Width is a property of block element. So to use property of width over an inline element or an element with display type inline set display as inline-block eg: display:inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

Combining `inline-flex` and `block` display elements worked for me.
In case someone would like to check a working example, here it is:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>inline demo</title>

    <style>
      .block_0 {
        display: inline-flex;
        width: 18rem;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        background-color: #85C1E9;
      }
      .block_1 {
          display: block;
          width:  4rem;
          padding: 0.5rem;
          background-color: #9B59B6;
      }
      .block_2 {
          display: block;
          width: 8rem;
          padding: 0.5rem;
          background-color: #6495ED;
      }
      .block_3 {
          display: block;
          width:  4rem;
          padding: 0.5rem;
          background-color: #DE3163;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      <span>some text</span>
      <span class="block_0">
          <span class="block_1">block_1</span>
          <span class="block_2">block_2</span>
          <span class="block_3">block_3</span>
      </span>
      <span>some text</span>
    </p>
  

  </body>
</html>
```