# I can't put a "style" and a "class" attribute on one html element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to neaten up some admin pages in an MVC 4.0 web project, and I'm running into some issues when applying both a class="" and a style="" to an html element. It seems that the class will override the inline styling.

CSS:

```
.adminHeader
{
   display: block;
   background: #3e3e3e;
   color: #fff;
}

.adminLabel
{
   display: inline;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 1.25em;
   font-weight: 600;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 1000px;">
    <div class="adminHeader">
        <span style="width: 200px;" class="adminLabel">bleh</span>
        <span style="width: 400px;" class="adminLabel">blaaaaaaaaaaah</span>
        <span style="width: 150px;" class="adminLabel">blu</span>
        <span style="width: 250px;" class="adminLabel">bluhh</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's happening is, the style="width:x;" will not be applied unless I remove the class attribute.  I know I can use multi-classing, but I don't want to have to create a million different CSS classes like .width150px, .width200px, etc.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!
Alex

Comment: shouldn't be. css's priority order makes `style=...` be the highest priority. anything in there should override anything applied via a "mere" class, unless the class has a `!important` override. Probably it's the `inline` directive. Spans are already by definition inline anyways.

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your quick response! The class does not have any !important tags in it. I just seems to be straight up ignoring anything I put into a style tag and using only the CSS from the class. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inline elements do not have width.  Your CSS specifies that the elements of that class should be inline.

There's a number of other questions covering this already.  For example, [Setting the width of inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423294/setting-the-width-of-inline-elements).

Comment: If you want them to have a width, they either have to have `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I removed the display:inline; from my adminLabel class but the inline style is still not applying...

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware that it was an issue of it being an inline element.  inline-block fixed it, thank you

Comment: Give the link I've edited into my answer a once over.  I suspect that there is a semantically more appropriate way to accomplish your goal without using spans.  It looks like you are trying to create some sort of tabbed navigation, in which case a UL with float:left would serve you better.

Comment: It's actually just a table, I changed it to divs and spans because prior research lead me to believe that tables don't play nice when you try to set specific widths.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `<span>` css  to `display: block;`. Span elements display inline by default.

```
span {display:block;}
```

Inline styles will always override stylesheet styles. See here in this example. *Also there is an example of using display block.*

http://jsfiddle.net/AHg7J/1/

Comment: I wasn't aware that inline elements could not have a specified width. Thank you!