# Trying to change width on hover using css

Tags: css, animation

I've done this before and I don't understand why it's not working. I'm trying to do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/geometron/u3M6r/1/

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="content1.html"> Demo 1     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content2.html"> Demo 2     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content3.html"> Demo 3     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content4.html"> Demo 4     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content5.html"> Demo 5     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content6.html"> Demo 6     </a></li>
</ul>
```

but with a ul so I can have less css. This is what I'm getting:
http://jsfiddle.net/geometron/6DUL9/

The width doesn't seem to want to change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423294/setting-the-width-of-inline-elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to display the anchor tag as a block type element, [otherwise it will not take the width property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width).

So try adding:

```
display:block;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
```

to your `ul li a` selector.

Here I add an update to your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DUL9/8/) for illustration.

Answer (score 1):

Tag `a` behaves a bit bad sometimes, especially when you try to specify the size.

A workaround is to specify `display: inline-block` for your `a`-tag. (It will however mess up the rest of your style.) 
See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DUL9/7/)

Better might be to change the width property of the `<li>`:s.

Answer (score 0):

You try to change the width of an inline element `a`.
To do this you need to add `display: inline-block;` to it.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an inline element. You cannot set a width on it directly. Add `display:inline-block` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your HTML

```
  <li  class="item1"><a href="content1.html"> Demo 1     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content2.html"> Demo 2     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content3.html"> Demo 3     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content4.html"> Demo 4     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content5.html"> Demo 5     </a></li>
    <li><a href="content6.html"> Demo 6     </a></li>
```

And try this in you CSS

```
.item1:hover
{
/*border-radius:100px;*/
height:25px;
left: 0px;
top: 130px;
width:250px;
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class = "sample">
<li><a href="content1.html"> Demo 1     </a></li>
<li><a href="content2.html"> Demo 2     </a></li>
<li><a href="content3.html"> Demo 3     </a></li>
<li><a href="content4.html"> Demo 4     </a></li>
<li><a href="content5.html"> Demo 5     </a></li>
<li><a href="content6.html"> Demo 6     </a></li>
```

CSS File

```
.sample li a:hover {
    padding: 4px 10px;
    }
```