# Width and text-align property

Tags: html, css

Why `text-align` and `width` are not applying to an inline element. [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/RAB9Y/) example.
Can you get a prooflink to a CSS spec?

Comment: ..make it an `inline-block` element. http://jsfiddle.net/NhCa4/

Comment: try adding `display: block;`

Comment: Is it true that CSS spec denies to apply width and text-align properties to an inline elements?

Comment: Yes because inline elements have no box properties like width, margin, padding. There's nothing for width to apply.

Comment: Can't you solve it with a block element like div? Normally, you shouldn't override these, better use a div. See this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423294/setting-the-width-of-inline-elements?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @JoshC Is there any better understanding for `display` property in css because often by different tries example: try `display: block` if not working change it to `inline-block` else.. it goes on.  any SO question you have crossed explaining these properties?

Comment: @BotskoNet Can you get a spec proof-link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `width`

> [10.3.1 Inline, non-replaced
>   elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width)
>
> **The 'width' property does not apply**. A computed value of 'auto' for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' becomes a used value of '0'.

### `text-align`

> [16.2 Alignment: the 'text-align'
>   property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-align)
>
> - Value:     left | right | center | justify | inherit
> - Initial:   a nameless value that acts as 'left' if 'direction' is 'ltr', 'right' if 'direction' is 'rtl'
> - **Applies to:      block containers**
> - Inherited:     yes
> - Percentages:   N/A
> - Media:     visual
> - Computed value:    the initial value or as specified

Quotes are from the CSS 2.1 specification.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<span>Some text</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span{
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:block;
    
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RAB9Y/5/)

**Output:**

[image]

To know more about Display Property ***[Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)***

**Updated:**

This can be achieved by this but it is not recommended for the following reasons

[Style sheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html) provide the means to specify the rendering of arbitrary elements, including whether an element is rendered as block or inline. In some cases, such as an inline style for list elements, this may be appropriate, but generally speaking, authors are discouraged from overriding the conventional interpretation of HTML elements in this way.

## **[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)**

Answer (score 0):

Size and align dont work well with span if at all. Wrap it or use a div.

```
<style type="text/css">
div{text-align:center; width:100%;}
</style>

<div>
<span>Some text</span>
</div>
```