# Making text elements in HTML take up a fixed amount of space without using tables?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page that has five buttons of width 50 arranged next to each other in a row, and above each one, I want there to be a text item.  However, putting each one in a `<span>` or a `<div style="display:inline">` does not pad them correctly with either "width="50"" or adding "width:50px" to the style; they just appear next to each other.  The "obvious" answer is to put each item into a table cell, but W3C says this is a Bad Thing now.

I also tried using input tags with readonly set; these space properly, but the text appears in input boxes rather than "on the page background."

Is there a way to align label elements (that can be changed in the script) evenly spaced horizontally without using a table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the width of inline elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423294/setting-the-width-of-inline-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements can't have fixed width or height. Try adding `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible solutions. Either you can use `display: table-cell`, which perfectly follows the W3C recommendations or you can use a flex box which is an even better solution. However the flex box is still quite new and you may want to support an older browser so the `display: table-cell` approach might work at least as a fallback.

Please, see the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfosmfab/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <span>Text 1</span>
        <span>Text 2</span>
        <span>Text 3</span>
        <span>Text 4</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements of `display: inline` don't take a `width` property, their size is dictated by their contents; to allow for elements to appear in-line with their siblings *and* to also accept a width switch their `display` property to that of `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because inline elements does not have fixed width. They are automatically set to fit in the space. You need to set `display: inline-block` to set width of an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
.btnbtnSpace{
 width:50px; 
 display: inline-block;
 }    
</style>


<div class="btnbtnSpace">Text<br /><button > 1</button></div>
<div class="btnbtnSpace">Text<br /><button > 2</button></div>
<div class="btnbtnSpace">Text<br /><button > 2</button></div>
<div class="btnbtnSpace">Text<br /><button > 4</button></div>
<div class="btnbtnSpace">Text<br /><button > 5</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"display: inline-block" worked.  I didn't notice it at first because the options on the "CSS Display" page at W3Schools didn't include it; inline-block gets its own page for some reason.