# How to make a codeblock with a defined width?

Tags: html, css, width, inline, styling

I'm trying to add a code block to a documentation website I'm making, but I can't make the block have a defined width. Its width is only tied to the text that's inside of it.

I want the block to have a set width and that the text simply falls in place within it, rather than having the code block restricted by the size of the text.

```css
* {
  width: 1265px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: inline-block;
}

main {
  margin: auto;
}

.centerContent {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

code {
  width: 600px;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  color: #43892a;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Batch Documentation</h1>
</header>
<main class="clearfix">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test2</li>
      <li>Test3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="centerContent">
    <h2>Sample text</h2>
    <code>Hello</code>
  </div>
</main>
```

funny enough: I'd like the code block to look like the code blocks in this site. Not talking about color but about their size.

Comment: If you want block level code rather than inline code you need to wrap the `<code>` tags in `<pre>` tags which will preserve the formatting of your code and render it in a block context..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<code>` element in HTML is by default an inline element and you cannot define a `width`, nor a `height` to an inline element.

The solution here is as simple as adding

`display: block`

in your element CSS for the following result

```
code {
  width: 600px;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  color: #43892a;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
}
```

For more information about inline and width, you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423294/setting-the-width-of-inline-elements)

Also, as [James Coyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1994081/james-coyle) pointed out, if you want to keep your code formatting instead of having it inline, you need to wrap the `<code>` tags in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: strange, but this also set width for my br texts in another column (I'm using it in a table)

Answer (score 0):

```
code {
  width: 600px;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  color: #43892a;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
}
```