# Why is width handled differently in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been playing around with `display:flex` lately as I see it becoming more trending. In a quick test, using flex and non-flex CSS approaches, I realized, my widths, and margins are always respected when using flex. Is this a good approach considering that I will most likely need a gutter between elements anyway? Moreover, where is the margin between spans coming from? This is what I mean:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="inner-box">This gives me a 30px X 60px</span>
    <span class="inner-box">This gives me a 30px X 60px</span>
    <span class="inner-box">This gives me a 30px X 60px</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="box2">
    <span class="inner-box">This gives me a width larger than the specified 30px</span>
    <span class="inner-box">This gives me a width larger than the specified 30px</span>
    <span class="inner-box">This gives me a width larger than the specified 30px</span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
  background: orange;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.box2{
  background: green;
  text-align:right;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.inner-box{
  width:30px;
  background:#fff;
  margin:0 0px;
}
```

Notice the widths at runtime
[image: Flexbox]

[image: Non-flexbox]

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgRNYX)

Comment: What is the question exactly? If `display:flex` honors `width`, where `display:inline` doesn't? If so, the answer is yes, but that wasn't very clear.

Comment: @MrLister, you are right, I missed to add the main question I have about this. I was in a rush when I had to post this. I edited

Comment: In your pen you have `.box2 span { display: inline-block }`, and the space between them is explained in [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630). In your question you don't have that, so they have the default `display: inline`, so they ignore `width` as explained in [Setting the width of inline elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1423294/1529630). Your question is a dupe of one of these.

Comment: No dupe.  But you can dupe it if you want.  It's ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `<span>` elements. They are inline by default. The `width` is automatically ignored for inline elements.

In the first `div` section (`.box`), however, the `span`'s inline `display` value is overridden by the parent's `display: flex`, which establishes a [*flex formatting context*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers). Hence, all children become flex items, which respect `width` and `height`.

> [**Flex Items**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> A flex item establishes a new formatting context for its contents. The
>   type of this formatting context is determined by its `display` value,
>   as usual. However, flex items themselves are ***flex-level*** boxes, not
>   block-level boxes: they participate in their container’s flex
>   formatting context, not in a block formatting context.
>
> *<sup>source: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items</sup>*

---

In the second `div` section (`.box2`), the `span` elements remain `display: inline`, as they are not removed from the [*block-formatting context*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting), and any `width` and `height` assignments are ignored.

Try `display: inline-block`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeggOy

References:

- [Setting the width of inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1423294/3597276)
- [How to set width of a inline element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5137772/3597276)
- [Does height and width not apply to span?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2491068/3597276)
- [Inline Elements With Width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085980/3597276)

Comment: This is a great and detail answer. I was looking for something like this to clarify the differences but to be the devil's advocate here. I tried display:inline-block and although it respected the width, it overflowed the text and still added the margins, unlike display flex

Comment: The whitespace you're seeing is a natural feature of `inline-block` elements. Here's the [**explanation**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32801275/3597276). Using one (of several) methods for removing the whitespace, here's your [**revised demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMWpNV).

Comment: font-size:0 !!!!! Who would've thought the font would have anything to do with this? Now, that, is a very interesting concept!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear but if, as MrLister commented:

*If `display:flex` honors width, where `display:inline` doesn't? If so, the answer is yes,*.

This is because, per the [**spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting),

> Flex items paint exactly the same as inline blocks

and so are affected by width statements.

Comment: The cool thing about your link reference (aside from the `inline-block` comparison) is that it highlights something probably not commonly known: flex items can use `z-order` without being positioned.

Comment: This interesting. Considering z-ordering can be a rescue sometimes but positioning can lead to more adjustments

Comment: I was in a rush when I posted, so I edited the question. But mainly my question is regarding to how are the widths handled and more importantly, where is the margin coming from?